# Using Avro GenericRecord with Confluent.Apache.Avro c# when having an array in Schema

Tags: c#, avro, confluent-platform

I have the following schema that contains an avro array type.

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "PersonalizationCustomerState_Payload",
  "namespace" : "com.aaa.qdh.personalization",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "consumer_id",
    "type" : "string"
  }, {
    "name" : "variables",
    "type" : {
      "type" : "array",
      "items" : {
        "type" : "record",
        "name" : "KeyValue",
        "fields" : [ {
          "name" : "name",
          "type" : "string"
        }, {
          "name" : "value",
          "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
          "default" : null
        } ]
      }
    }
  } ]
}
```

I would like to Use generic record to publish an event that uses this schema. But I didnt find a way how I could use generic record to inject the array data using confluent .net libraries.  I found how we could do it in java [populating nested records with array in Avro using a GenericRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50278222/populating-nested-records-with-array-in-avro-using-a-genericrecord/50295641) but seems like .net version of Avro doesn't have the similar features.

Below is the code that I have so far. The problem is that the variables field use an array schema, so it throws an exception from the line **new GenericRecord((RecordSchema)variables.Schema);**. And GenericRecord expects a RecordSchema.

```
                    var schema = (RecordSchema)Avro.Schema.Parse(
                        File.ReadAllText("asvc/PersonalizationCustomerState_Payload.avsc"));
                    var record = new GenericRecord(schema);
                    record.Add("consumer_id", "10");

                    ((RecordSchema)schema).TryGetField("variables", out Field variables);
                    var array = new GenericRecord((RecordSchema)variables.Schema);
                    // how to add to an array? 


                    record.Add("variables", array);
```

Could you please explain me how to do this?

Comment: Could you share your code so far?

Comment: @cricket_007 Edited the question to include the code and highlighted where it caused the problem.

Comment: Your schema has no event_id. Is that the correct code?

Comment: @cricket_007  I modified schema a bit for the question to remove not related content but forgot to remove the unrelated parts from the code. Now I have modified the code too.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't generate a specific type using the codegen tool?

Comment: @cricket_007 I can (and I use SpecificRecords at my consumer). But the publisher is using the GenericRecord (And I dont have a control over the publisher). So for the integration tests I thought of using the GenericRecord (to simulate the publisher), and make sure my consumer works as expected.

Comment: Okay, well, I see there's an ArraySchema class, and I think arrays are primitive types in Avro, not Record objects. I'm not seeing examples how to define one though https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/api/csharp/html/classAvro_1_1ArraySchema.html